# OpenCV 3.0 + Visual Studio Memory Leak Detector "false" positive

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, opencv3.0

I would like to create project with enabled Visual Studio memory leak detector ([Memory Leak Detector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.90).aspx))

It always worked fine and I could easily find memory leaks by running bunch of tests on my application and then checking the report.

But after statically linking OpenCV 3.0 to my project I got some false positives.

For instance the most frustrating error comes from `StereoBMImpl::compute` method and call: `ocl::useOpenCL()`

After debugging I found the source of the "leak":

```
TLSData<CoreTLSData>& getCoreTlsData()
{
    static TLSData<CoreTLSData> *value = new TLSData<CoreTLSData>();
    return *value;
}
```

After analyzing this code we know the static object is allocated only once and everything should be OK. But now I have bunch of false positive memory leak reports like:

```
{1370349} normal block at 0x0E74D560, 24 bytes long.
 Data: <                > FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{1370348} normal block at 0x0E74D4E0, 64 bytes long.
 Data: <` t             > 60 D5 74 0E CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD
```

And now it's very difficult to find some real memory leaks in my application because there is set of false positives from OpenCV. I can't also run automatic memory leak tests because the output always contains some leaks.

Is there any way to remove these "pseudo" errors (if possible without changing OpenCV source code) ? It's very annoying.

I suppose other memory leaks detectors will also report some similar pseudo leaks because the `new` operator is executed without `delete` (object is automatically cleaned up by the OS).

Comment: That's not a false positive, that's an actual memory leak.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I agree, but unfortunately it won't be fixed in OpenCv. I reported this issue ( https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5452 ), but it was marked as wontfix (it's workaround for "static initialization/desctruction order fiasco"). Any ideas how to deal with this issue ?

Comment: If modifying OpenCv is an option, then you could alter the `getCoreTlsData()` function to explicitly pass a block type to the debug operator new, e.g. `new (_IGNORE_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) TlsData<CoreTLSData>()`.  Alternatively (but uglierly), you can free the block yourself before you perform the leak check, via `delete &getCoreTlsData();`.  But this would require careful timing: you'd have to make sure that you did this _after_ OpenCv is done using it.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis thanks a lot, it wasn't as simple as you proposed, but it showed me a way to suspend memory leaks checking. I described my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem in a quite dirty way, but I didn't find better. The solution requires modifying one OpenCV file (system.cpp). If you found a better way to fix it, please leave a comment. I suppose more people might have similar problems.

First I tried to solve the problem using @JamesMcNellis solution (from comment above), by explicitly mark the block as _IGNORE_BLOCK: `new (_IGNORE_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__)`. It was really good start to solve this problem. Unfortunately the leak class contains members like e.g. `std::vector`, so tracing the allocations from this vector weren't suspended.

I started to read MSDN documentation to functions from `crtdbg.h` and I found a way to suspend memory leaks checking for a while. It's possible by clearing the flag '_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF' using function: `_CrtSetDbgFlag`. Check details with example on MSDN: [_CrtSetDbgFlag documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/5at7yxcs.aspx).
This solution has probably one drawback (one I know), It suspends memory leaks checking for all threads.

Finally using RAII and few macro definitions I created simple class to manage this functionality.

All the changes I applied to official 3.0 source codes.

Somewhere on top (after precomp.hpp include) of `system.cpp` file from OpenCV I added simple machinery:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_DEBUG)
    #include <crtdbg.h>
    class MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING_SUSPENDER
    {
    public:
        MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING_SUSPENDER()
        {
            value = _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG);
            int new_flag = value & (~_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF);
            _CrtSetDbgFlag(new_flag);
        }

        ~MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING_SUSPENDER()
        {
            _CrtSetDbgFlag(value);
        }

    private:
        int value;
    };

    #define SUSPEND_MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING_SUSPENDER suspend_memory_leaks_checking
#else
    #define SUSPEND_MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING
#endif
```

And each time I want to suspend memory leaks checking i have to add: `PAUSE_MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING;` It is enabled only in Visual Studio Debug compilation. The memory leaks tracing is automatically enabled after leaving the scope (destructor of `MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING_SUSPENDER` class).

Currently to suspend my OpenCV memory leaks I added suspending allocations in functions:

- `getTLSContainerStorage()`
- `void* TLSDataContainer::getData() const`
- `TLSData<CoreTLSData>& getCoreTlsData()`
- `inline TLSStorage* TLSStorage::get()`

(The last suspension in TLSStorage is probably fixed on master OpenCV repository - I briefly checked the repository)

Each modification is very simple (e.g. for first leak):

Before modification:

```
static TLSContainerStorage& getTLSContainerStorage()
{
    static TLSContainerStorage *tlsContainerStorage = new TLSContainerStorage();
    return *tlsContainerStorage;
}
```

After modification:

```
static TLSContainerStorage& getTLSContainerStorage()
{
    SUSPEND_MEMORY_LEAKS_CHECKING;
    static TLSContainerStorage *tlsContainerStorage = new TLSContainerStorage();
    return *tlsContainerStorage;
}
```

---

If you modify all these statements and still observe memory leaks and you use OpenCV as separately loaded dll then make sure you properly unloaded this dll using `FreeLibrary` function. For the reason check `DLLMain` function in OpenCV `system.cpp` file and `cv::__termination` variable usage.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and your solution works for me. You could accept your own answer I think.

Comment: AdamF, have you tried this with OpenCV 3.2? I'm using it as a shared library (DLL) and I get memory leaks even if the only other reference to OpenCV in my project is creating a cv::Mat. I tried to apply your solution but the leaks continue, and I'm not sure how to track them down. Also, there's no getTLSContainerStorage(), so I added your suspender to static TlsStorage &getTlsStorage() which I'm guessing replaced it. There's no inline TLSStorage* TLSStorage::get() either, so I placed the suspender in the void* getData(size_t slotIdx) const member of TlsStorage. But, still leaks. Same in 3.3.

Comment: @DisplayName I have tried to provide quick fix for OpenCV 3.3, but unfortunately the amount of such leaks in the recent version is much bigger. You could try to modify the library, but it is not the right way. In my opinion OpenCV developers should fix these leaks or at least add possibility to disable MSVC leak detector in their code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem  in my project: statical build - MFC & OpenCV.  Those solutions didn't help me.  I tested them with OpenCV versions:  3.4.3 and 4.0.1. The issue went out when all opencv functions were  into their own dlls.  So my project configuration can be  the following:  MFC build - static, OpenCV - dynamic

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to debug the opencv part you can maybe use the release lib in debug mode, On this way it can avoid all false positive leaks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I have an alternative workaround:

Make a special function, say, `prefetchOpenCvMemoryLeaks()`, which creates/destroys a small matrix, creates/destroys a small window, and so on, so that `OpenCV` leaks are saturated.

In the outer `main()` function, save heap state with `_CrtMemCheckpoint()`, call the entire project, at the end save heap state again and compare it with the old one by `_CrtMemDifference()`.

This way you can check your own memory leaks regardless of `OpenCV` ones.