# Linking opencv 3.2 to an MFC project causes false memory leaks

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, linker

I recently linked openCV to my MFC project which ran before without any memory leaks,
when I added something as simple as

```
void function {
   Mat image;
}
```

visual studio detects a lot of memory leaks, which seems false positives  . this problem was fixed by delay loading the opencv_world320d.dll in the linker, but if I try to do something with the images like reading into it or using canny's edge detector the memory leaks reappear.

I also tried to statically load MFC library with no success.

(I run the same function on a new project without the MFC, and it works without leaks)

any suggestions on how to fix it? would really appreciate your help!

Thanks

here is the loading order:

```
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded '******as2000pc.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc140ud.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
**'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\****\opencv_world320d.dll'. Symbols** loaded.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.14393.447_none_5507ded2cb4f7f4c\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\concrt140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.14393.953_none_baad48403594ab3f\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mpr.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.14393.953_none_89c2555adb023171\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86\FM20.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\riched20.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msls31.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sxs.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86\FM20ENU.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\quartz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qcap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qedit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devenum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdmo.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\BaslerGenICamSource_v5_0.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\MVGenICamConfig_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\PylonBase_MD_VC120_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\Log_MD_VC120_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\GCBase_MD_VC120_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\GenApi_MD_VC120_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\MathParser_MD_VC120_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\XmlParser_MD_VC120_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\NodeMapData_MD_VC120_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\log4cpp_MD_VC120_v3_0_Basler_pylon_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\PylonUsb_MD_VC120_V5_0_TL.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\uxapi_MD_VC120_v5_0.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uEyecapture.ax'. Module was built without symbols.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uEye_api.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dim700.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxva2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\coml2.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvd3dum.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxva2.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devenum.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\quartz.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uEyecapture.ax'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\MVGenICamConfig_v5_0.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\PROGRA~1\Basler\pylon 5\Runtime\Win32\BaslerGenICamSource_v5_0.ax'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qedit.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msls31.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\riched20.dll'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86\FM20ENU.DLL'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86\FM20.DLL'
'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qcap.dll'
```

Comment: "I also tried to statically load MFC library with no success." - that doesn't really explain much, does it?

Comment: I loaded the library as static and the memory leaks remained, it was suggested to do so in some posts.

Comment: There's hardly anything you can do about those false positives. They are caused by objects with static storage duration, that are instantiated after leak checking starts, but only destroyed when the CRT unloads (which is too late for leak checking to take into account). Singleton implementations frequently follow this pattern, and cause false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using opencv version 2.4.13 instead of 3.2 and loading delayed opencv ddls fixed the false memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced an identical situation, here's my 2c.

When the application starts up you should get module-load messages in the VS output pane (if not, right click it and check 'Module load messages').  Take note of the module loading order - in particular mfc***.dll.  Any of your modules that load *before* that will be unloaded *after* it, and thus any static allocations they make would be falsely reported as leaks.

In my particular situation I was lucky, and I detected one module of mine that was loaded early and not built as an MFC module. Changing it to an MFC dll made the mfc framework load earlier, and these false leaks were gone.

That might be also the case for you. But I have no general solution.

Comment: tried checking the loading order, seems only SysWOW64 dlls load before the mfc140ud.dll, so i dont think this works for me :(

Comment: Can you paste the complete loading/unloading messages in the question?

Comment: I compiled an older version of opencv 2.4.13 and it seems that the memory leaks were fixed by the delay loading of the dlls
but I would still like to find a solution on opencv 3.2

Comment: added the loading output while using opencv 3.2.

Comment: The loading order you dumped includes mfc very early on and *doesn't* include opencv at all. Delay-loading opencv should indeed be a valid workaround - but is that the case for the loading dump you pasted?

Comment: I just changed the project path to ****** so it wont show.
(1) I think it uses kernel32 because i was getting an error that it cant find it few weeks ago.
(2) it should be an MFC app already, it uses MFC shared dll.
 or am I missing something?

Comment: @mikero where is opencv in this dump?

Comment: the loading order I pasted was before I added opencv_world320d.dll to be delayed.
delaying only worked on older version of opencv => 2.4.13 and what I pasted was for 3.2.
it does  show the opencv load "**'as2000pc.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\****\opencv_world320d.dll'. Symbols** loaded." edited it so it is easier to see.

there is some problem integrating the new opencv with MFC and the only fix I could find was changing the code to delay memory leak checks .
it is shown here:   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845535/opencv-3-0-visual-studio-memory-leak-detector-false-positive)

Comment: I see now, thanks.  In your case OpenCv is loaded *after* MFC, and whatever it leaves unreleased upon unloading should indeed count as a leak. What exactly makes you say the leak reports are false?

Comment: (1) all the opencv code is in a single function, I pasted it into a new project and it works without leaks.
(2) I removed most of the code and left something simple as {Mat image;} => the leaks appeared, delaying the dll load at this point helped, until I added another line of code that loads an image => leaks appeared again.
(3) the older version doesn't show leaks.

Comment: I just tested on my project, and delay-loading is an alternate solution that works for me.   I don't see how adding a line of code that loads an image can break delay-loading - are you positive that is the situation?

Comment: If you can build OpenCv yourself, you might also want to check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845535/opencv-3-0-visual-studio-memory-leak-detector-false-positive?rq=1

Comment: *"whatever it leaves unreleased upon unloading should indeed count as a leak."* - That's the wrong conclusion. This isn't about leaving resources unreleased. It is about modules being unloaded after MFC. In other words: The cleanup runs, but does so after MFC has done its memory leak checking. This is a false positive. The only robust solution would be to ensure, that MFC is the first (non-system) library loaded, and the last (non-system) library unloaded. Not sure how one would achieve this, though.

Comment: @IInspectable In the scenario of the OP openCV is unloaded before MFC, so any allocations it (openCV)makes that are still caught by MFC should count as leaks